# Airflow email config settings

Tags: python, airflow

I am reading through airflow documentation and trying to understand what would be the difference in the from sender email in the different sections of the configuration file:

What is the difference between :

```
[smtp] 
smtp_mail_from=<johndoe@example.com> 

[email]
from_email = "John Doe <johndoe@example.com>"
```

In this case the email is the same but what if I had different emails in the email section and smtp section. Which sender is picked if I use the email operator or the send_mail util function?